# Get Child with Focus inside NSSplitView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nssplitview

I have an `NSSplitViewController` which has two child view controllers. I have a menu action that is passed to the split view controller and I want to be able to send the action triggered by the menu to the appropriate child controller.

For example if I had one list on either side of the split, I would want a delete menu action to be passed to the one the user is focussed on.

I don't really want to implement remembering which child is focussed myself, if I can avoid it.

Comment: What happens if you connect the menu action to First Responder?

Comment: Did you find solution? Could you show it? I have the same problem =(

Comment: No, I haven't worked out a way of doing it. If I do then I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Willeke was right - connecting first responders up makes it work.

Both view controllers (each child of the split view) need to implement some method that will get called - in my case `deleteItems:`. The delete action in the menu then links to the first responder with name `deleteItems:`.

The method will be called on the active view controller when the menu is selected.